# Modal popup is using the masterpage

Tags: master-page

When in Documents page, clicking "new folder" or "new document" brings up a modal popup. This modal is in an iframe which is using the sites masterpage layout. So I'm seeing the site Breadcrumb again inside the modal.  Also, all CSS and Script references are loaded again in the mobile because of this.

Is there a way to remove the modal popups from using the site masterpage?

Answer (score 1):

By Default you can not use different css for modal popup. Add the `s4-notdlg` class to the elements you don’t want to render in a popup. 
Using JavaScript you can find the page is either opened in modal popup or full window based on the situation you can apply or load different CSS.
`isDlg=1`  is added in the URL if it is opened in a modal popup.